# Multiplacation in PHP without * and /

Tags: php, math

So I am trying to make a multiplication app without using division or subtraction. To do this I am using Ethiopian multiplication which uses << and >>. The code will not shift Num2 to the right for some reason.

I dont really know how to fix it but here is the code if anyone can help.

```
<?php 


function ethMul($num1, $num2){
    $count = 0;
    while($num2 > 1){
        #number stuff
        $num1 << 1;
        $num2 >> 1;
        #drops decimal
        $num2 = (int) $num2;
        echo $num2;
        #uses EM to take num5 and make it equal to $num3>>1 and then make num6 equal to $num5<<1;
        $num3 = $num1 >> 1;
        $num4 = $num3 << 1;
        #if statement for adding to the
        if ($num4 = $num1){
            $count += $num1;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}


echo ethMul(17, 12);
```

Comment: Is this inherently Ethiopian? Or should we simply call it "Bit Math" or "Math via Bit Shifting"?

Comment: `$num2 >> 1` does not modify `$num2`. Assign the result back to `$num2`. Also, The result of a bit shift operation is already an integer, you do not need to cast it.

Comment: @mickmackusa seems to be more commonly known as ["Russian Peasant Multiplication"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication#Russian_peasant_multiplication).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple replica of multiplying two positive integers. $fac2 >>= 1; is a simplified notation for $fac2 = $fac2 >> 1;

```
function mul($fac1,$fac2){
  for($prod = 0;$fac2;$fac2 >>=  1){
    if($fac2 & 1) $prod += $fac1;
    $fac1 <<= 1;
  }
  return $prod;
}

echo mul(7,6);  //42
```